# Bold text with times package and pdfLaTeX

Tags: fonts, pdftex, times

I use `pdfLaTeX` and `\usepackage{times}` for my document and cannot understand why there is no bold text in my document. I tried to use `\rmfamily` (it works), but it is not the same, right?)

if somebody know way to write bold and use times-a-like font please let me know

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=25mm, right=10mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[english,russian,ukrainian]{babel}

\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}

\textbf{qqqqq}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know the reason for this, but commenting `\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[english,russian,ukrainian]{babel}` works.

Comment: It might be interesting to read the documentation of the `nag` package to learn which packages are obsolete.

Comment: You could switch to xelatex or lualatex and use `Time New Roman` as font https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Fd9F.png

Comment: @Niranjan my I'm writing report in ukrainian, so I have to use it =)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yes, I tried xelatex , but it couse some errors and after it resolving it does not work too

Comment: @WinnieNotThePooh Try this code: https://pastebin.com/xjHAhjJT

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thank you, but the code gives me some errors...

Comment: @WinnieNotThePooh If you don't say which errors you get, it is hard trying to help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a Times clone that also supports Cyrillic: Tempora.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=25mm, right=10mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian,ukrainian]{babel}

\usepackage{tempora}

\begin{document}

\textbf{qqqqq}

Київ \textbf{Київ}

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz (Tempora)

{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz (Times)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why didn't you get boldface? If you look in the log file, you'll see

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/ptm/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T2A/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 9.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/ptm/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T2A/ptm/m/n' instead on input line 11.
```

The `ptm` font family doesn't support the T2A (Cyrillic) encoding, so a substitution with the default font family is performed. Next, LaTeX realizes you want `b` (bold face) and substitutes the only font in the family `ptm` with encoding T2A it know (which is actually the substitute, so Computer Modern Cyrillic in medium series).

Comment: Thank you very much, it is literally a "clone" of times.

Answer (score 2):

Use a font that has a T2A encoding, `times` doesn't has it! Use for example  `libertine` instead of `times`:

```
\usepackage{libertine}
```

[image]